# changed server.port in application.properties but not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, application.properties

I have changed the server.port=7070 in application.properties but still its picking 8080 port instead of the modified one.

can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Is that spring-boot application with application.properties placed under /src/main/resources ? Reference material : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_application_properties.htm

Comment: please provide  a full context of what have you done 
show me the config file and also i want to see a picture of your folder structure also how are you running the app

Comment: make this updates and I will be able to help you, usnig maven try this : mvn clean spring-boot:run

Comment: Can you please share as to how you are configuring your TomcatServletWebServerFactory in spring?

Answer (score 0):

Check the structure of the code and make sure that application.propertise under resources